# scipy simulated annealing optimizer aversion to testing neighborhood of an optimal point

Tags: simulated-annealing

As I understand simulated annealing, when the algorithm finds a point that is the best solution thus far, the space around that solution should be searched more frequently.  However, I've been using s[cipy.optimize.dual_annealing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html) for a while and it defies my expectations more often than I would imagine possible by chance.  This is the scatter of a 2D simulated annealing where the larger (and darker red) a point is, the more optimal it is.  Note that in the space around it, there are very few points.

[image]

The most obvious explanation for this is that I somehow inverted or negated the value to be minimized, but this is not the case.  Another explanation is that I stopped the simulated annealing shortly after the discovery of largest dot.  But it appears at sample 75 out of over 120 samples.  The odds that after almost 50 samples, there would be no samples in the region around the best-so-far is pretty small.  Another explanation is that the largest dot obscures a high density of samples around it but this is not the case either.
[image]

Nor is this an isolated incident.  So what is a possible explanation?

Comment: First, it's near the boundary of the region, which means there are a lot fewer  (informally) points "near" it than near a point in the middle of the region.  Second, if your step size - the distance between a point and the next proposal - is large, the next step will carry you some distance away from the optimal point, and it might be a while before you get back.   Third, that point seems surrounded by not very good points, so unless there's a proposal that by chance lands very close to it, you're possibly rejecting the proposals that would get you close to it.

Comment: Can you make a contour plot or some such of the function you are working with?